# Can any struts property be specified in struts.xml instead?

Tags: struts2

Can any Struts constant in the `struts.properties` file also be specified in `struts.xml`?  This would enable us to set the value with environment variables

For example, can the following constants in the properties file:

```properties
struts.ognl.logMissingProperties=true
struts.el.throwExceptionOnFailure=false
```

be instead specified in `struts.xml` as the following?

```xml
<constant name="struts.ognl.logMissingProperties" value="${env.logmissing}"/>
<constant name="struts.el.throwExceptionOnFailure" value="${env.throwExc}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration properties in `struts.properties` *can* be specified in `struts.xml`. The first file can be used to change global properties if you don't have `struts.xml`.

So the properties from the `struts.properties` file would be in `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.ognl.logMissingProperties" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.el.throwExceptionOnFailure" value="false"/>
```